# XCode 4.2.1 under Lion -- TURN OFF SPELL CHECKING; is there a way?

Tags: macos

Every time I open XCode, my various "notes" files which are part of the project show up with ALL of my variable names, etc., in notes to myself, underlined in red.

I can turn it off with a right-click and a dropdown.

EVERY time I restart, it's back to that obnoxious behavior again.

It *is* turned off in System Prefs.

Is ther ANY way to make this PERMANENT?

Comment: You don't want to upgrade to 4.4.1 (not sure if that changes anything though)?

Comment: Actually I came back here to comment that I'd read somewhere that it was a new setting in 4.4 or 4.4.1, which of course implies that there wasn't a way to do so before!  You beat me to it.  Though I haven't committed yet to 4.4+ as 10.7.4 breaks my opencl kernel and I've not yet figured out why.  I guess that does need to be addressed!...